# Let $M_i$ be the free $\mathbb Z$ module $\mathbb Z,$ and let $M$ be the direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, modules

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Let $M_i$ be the free $\mathbb Z$ module $\mathbb Z,$ and let $M$ be the direct product $\Pi_{i\in \mathbb Z^+}M_i.$ Each element of $M$ can be written uniquely in the form $(a_1, a_2,a_3, \dots )$ with $a_i \in \mathbb Z$ for all $i.$ Let $N$ be the submodule of $M$ consisting of all such tuples with only finitely many nonzero $a_i.$ Assume $M$ is a free $\mathbb Z$ module with basis $\mathcal B.$

$(a)$ Show that $N$ is countable.

**My idea is:**

I should show that there is a bijection from the set of natural numbers to $N.$ I am guessing that the following map in the following picture might work (I found it online) :

[image]

But I am not sure what is $N^+$ in the solution, where should be the beside $\phi_n$? Why the domain is $\mathbb Z^n$?

Could anyone help me answer these questions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $N^+$ is simply the positive natural numbers and $\phi_n$ is an inclusion of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ into $N$, so we end up writing $N$ as a countable union of (countable) images of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. If you want a bijection of $N$ with a countable set, click below

> Alternatively, consider sending $(a_1, a_2, \dots)$ to the continued fraction $$a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+\frac{1}{\dots}}$$ when $a_i\geq 0$ (terminate the fraction appropriately when you encounter a tail of zeroes). This gives a nonnegative rational number when only finitely many $a_i$s are nonzero and is bijective (note that $a_1$ is the floor of the continued fraction...) Using a bijection $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{N}$, one can get an bijection $N\to\mathbb{Q}_{\geq 0}$ showing that $N$ is countable.

Comment: but why we are excluding the zero from the natural numbers even though our I starts with zero?

Comment: @Secretly I'm not sure about the author's conventions, they use both $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{N}^+$, but I hope their idea is clear to you.

Comment: But what is the $i$ beside the $\phi_n$ in the solution?should it be a subscript?

Comment: How did we know that the images of $\phi_n$ are countable?

Comment: Why we have a power $n$ on $\mathbb Z$ in the domain of the function?

Comment: why the index of $a$ is shifted in the image?

Comment: Yes, I think the $i$ should be a subscript, indicating what the $i$th coordinate is. The images of $\phi_n$ are countable because $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is countable. We have a power on $\mathbb{Z}$ because we want the image to be that subset of $N$ where things beyond the $n+1$st coordinate are zero (which means we have $n$-tuples of integers). As for the shift, I suspect it's because of whatever conventions the author is working with.